# Device identification authentication like in google / facebook

Tags: html, ios, facebook, security, web

How to identify user's device on authentication -- such that second factor auth (such as SMS) can be enforced if user is logging in from an unknown device? I've seen google and facebook has this feature, and they're not using a simple IP check -- if I have two devices on the same network, it can still detect if I tried logging in from an unknown device.

Especially on websites -- as far as I know we can only get user's IP, and other information on HTTP headers, but how do we identify the user's device securely?

Answer (score 2):

You could use cookies - if the user doesn't have the appropriate cookie, then require a successful two factor authentication?

You could also consider [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org) in combination with IP address / geo-ip information for a more heuristic approach, though that would be a lot more complex to implement and likely more fragile.